# When are normal forms computable in amalgamated produts and HNN extensions

Tags: gr.group-theory, computability-theory

I have had little luck searching for references on the following. I would thank a lot any reference.

> What are known conditions that ensure computable normal forms on amalgamated products and HNN extension?

I would thank any reference.

Say that we have a group $G$ which is an amalgamated product $H\ast _C K$ or HNN extensions  $H\ast _\phi $.
In both cases we have normal forms (as in the known books by Lyndon & Schupp or Magnus), and if those normal forms are computable then the word problem of $G$ is decidable.
If the word problem for $G$ is decidable, that does not seem to imply this normal form to be computable (still don't get an example).

Comment: If memory serves me correctly to solve the word problem in a finite graph of groups you need the word problem for the vertex groups and the membership problem for the edge groups in each of the "two" vertex groups associated to the edge

Comment: Perhaps there also needs to be some computability requirement connected to the edge-to-vertex group monomorphism themselves...